# What is the first order derivative of linear regression's cost function using matrix calculus?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-algebra, calculus, matrix-calculus

For linear regression's cost function J(b), where X is a n*m matrix, b is a m*1 vector and y is n*1 vector:

[image]

First order derivative with respect to vector b (coefficients) is shown to be

[image]

Using the chain rule of 'general calculus',
shouldn't the derivative be

[image]

[image]

Can someone please show the step by step derivative of the chain rule using matrix calculus?

(I understand that all the matrix dimensions align with matrix-multiplication rules when using equation 1)

Comment: The matrix cookbook gives a good list of derivatives of various vectors and matrices: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf.  But also, you can just check the dimensions.  $Xb - y$ is n*1, so it can't be multiplied on the right (or left for that matter) by $X$ which is n*m.

Comment: @NickKoprowicz Thanks for the pdf. Looks very comprehensive!